# Changing width/height moves rotated element

Tags: jquery, css, rotation, transform

When changing the width/height of a rotated elements, the element moves!

Here's an example
**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/unloco/ww8k4hy4/)**

When I change the width for example, the object loses its original position, this is effecting jQueryUI Resizable and making it unusable.

CSS:

```
.test{
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left; 200px;

    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;

    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/unloco/ww8k4hy4/)**
Is there a library or a function that corrects this issue by reversing this effect.

**Edit:**
I made a jQuery function that corrects the top-left position upon resizing a rotated element, added as answer.
Also this is a **[patch for jqueryui resizable](http://jsfiddle.net/unloco/ors6d3xe/)**

Comment: try adding half of the 'width' to the 'top' value once you rotate it.  I think the transform:rotate takes the center of the object.

Comment: @user1269942 I'm looking for a formula to reverse this effect and kind of restore the element position, i've been testing sine and cosine but with no luck so far !

Comment: I think you have to add half the difference in width to `top` and subtract the same from `left` while increasing width and do the opposite while decreasing width. See the comments in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ww8k4hy4/12/)

Comment: maybe a diagram of what you want can be useful. do you just want to preserve the top and left values when transformed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This jQuery function will change the size of the element and make necessary correction to preserve the top-left corner position

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/unloco/ww8k4hy4/15/)**

```
/**
* Resizes rotated set of elements and preserves top-left corner position
* @param {Number} new_width
* @param {Number} new_height
* @param {Number} angle in degrees
* @returns {object} the current jQuery set
*/
$.fn.rotSize = function(new_width, new_height, angle){

    //Convert angle from degrees to radians
    var angle = angle * Math.PI / 180

    $(this).each(function(i, elem){
        var $elem = $(elem);
        //initial CSS position.
        var pos = {left: parseInt($elem.css('left')), top: parseInt($elem.css('top'))};
        var init_w = $elem.width();
        var init_h = $elem.height();
        //Get position after rotation with original size
        var x = -init_w/2;
        var y = init_h/2;
        var new_x = y * Math.sin(angle) + x * Math.cos(angle);
        var new_y = y * Math.cos(angle) - x * Math.sin(angle);
        var diff1 = {left: new_x - x, top: new_y - y};

        //Get position after rotation with new size
        var x = -new_width/2;
        var y = new_height/2;
        var new_x = y * Math.sin(angle) + x * Math.cos(angle);
        var new_y = y * Math.cos(angle) - x * Math.sin(angle);
        var diff2 = {left: new_x - x, top: new_y - y};

        //Get the difference between the two positions
        var offset = {left: diff2.left - diff1.left, top: diff2.top - diff1.top};
        //Calculate the correction
        var new_pos = {left: pos.left - offset.left, top: pos.top + offset.top};

        //Apply
        $elem.css(new_pos);
        $elem.css({width: new_width, height: new_height});
    });
}
```

Another useful function:

```
/**
* Calculate the size correction for resized rotated element
* @param {Number} init_w
* @param {Number} init_h
* @param {Number} delta_w
* @param {Number} delta_h
* @param {Number} angle in degrees
* @returns {object} correction css object {left, top}
*/
$.getCorrection = function(init_w, init_h, delta_w, delta_h, angle){
    //Convert angle from degrees to radians
    var angle = angle * Math.PI / 180

    //Get position after rotation with original size
    var x = -init_w/2;
    var y = init_h/2;
    var new_x = y * Math.sin(angle) + x * Math.cos(angle);
    var new_y = y * Math.cos(angle) - x * Math.sin(angle);
    var diff1 = {left: new_x - x, top: new_y - y};

    var new_width = init_w + delta_w;
    var new_height = init_h + delta_h;

    //Get position after rotation with new size
    var x = -new_width/2;
    var y = new_height/2;
    var new_x = y * Math.sin(angle) + x * Math.cos(angle);
    var new_y = y * Math.cos(angle) - x * Math.sin(angle);
    var diff2 = {left: new_x - x, top: new_y - y};

    //Get the difference between the two positions
    var offset = {left: diff2.left - diff1.left, top: diff2.top - diff1.top};
    return offset;
}
```

Comment: This works great! What modifications would be needed if the bottom-right needs to be preserved though?

Comment: @ImraanKhan could you please take a look on similar question? I'm trying to reuse the code in my example but left-top corner shifts still https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59427665/resize-rotated-object-without-left-top-corner-shift

Answer (score 1):

`transform-origin` is set to `centre` by default, and when you change the width/height of the element, the original centre moves, thus moving your object.

<s>see this updated fiddle, with a fix for changing width http://jsfiddle.net/ww8k4hy4/6/</s>

**EDIT**

Set both values of `transform-origin` to be half of width -- see this: http://jsfiddle.net/ww8k4hy4/10/

(figuring this out proved to be very helpful for me too, so thanks :) )

Comment: I was aiming towards an equation/formula to reverse the effect, thank you

Comment: This fiddle lets you visualise this a little easier: http://jsfiddle.net/ww8k4hy4/7/

Comment: My friend, I need an equation :-) one that would work for any angle/dimensions thank you

Comment: Well what do you mean by the 'object loses its initial position' ? Obviously, as you transform it, its appearance on the page will change, though the space it occupies remains the same. See this: http://cdn.css-tricks.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/aftertransform.png  There could be a formula to transform such that one point/line always lines up to the original space - but you would need to specify what this constraint is

Comment: `transform-origin` is very interesting but it also requires more calculation in order for it to work for all angles and size differences

Comment: Yup, visualising for top-left alignment as opposed to smartly choosing centre does seem easier - will try out your function below. Did you look into matrix transforms at all btw? Not sure, but maybe that would be one approach as well