# How to preserve the bottom-right position when changing the height of a rotated dom element?

Tags: javascript, css

As demonstrated [here](http://jsfiddle.net/g8my3v6d/1/). When changing the width/height of an element that is rotated by some angle. The element moves.

How is it possible to fix and preserve the position of the element at the bottom right or any other corner for that matter when the width or height of the element is changed. And without changing the transform origin.

CSS:

```
.test{
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 200px;

  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;

  transform: rotate(120deg);
}
```

Comment: The answer to this question shows how to preserve the top-left position. But I fail to understand the formula and the calculation used. And what modifications would be needed to preserve bottom-right instead of top-left
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25985630/changing-width-height-moves-rotated-element

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by absolutely positioning the .test object using percentages and then offsetting those with transform. By replacing your .test css with the css below you will make the center of the object align to the center of the container no matter what its size is:

```
.test{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    transform: translate(50%, 50%) rotate(120deg);

    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
}
```

To not make the object centered you will have to play around with the percentages of the bottom, right and translate properties.