# Resize rotated object preserving left top corner (sub-pixel rendering issue)

Tags: javascript, math, rotation, resize

I'm trying to resize rotated (transformed with css) object with vanilla js. Object origin is center and can't be changed.

I've found a function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25985630/changing-width-height-moves-rotated-element) which should do the thing, however still it doesn't looks ideal - left top corner change its position (half of pixels or so).

Here is a simplified [codepen example](https://codepen.io/vdenisenko-waverley/pen/BayWORo?editors=1010).

What code modifications I need to do at `getCorrection` to keep left top corner position always same?

UPDATE:

As per comments below, the calculation is accurate but browser just can't deal with fractions of a pixel perfectly which seems like a technical limitation? Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: `r` should be 20, not 30 in this case. You can also read the angle using a function, check `getAngle` here https://github.com/unlocomqx/jQuery-ui-resizable-rotation-patch/blob/master/resizable-rotation.patch.js#L255

Comment: good point @UnLoCo! it helped a bit! Now still if you continue clicking on button you'll see some small shift of left-top corner (half of pixel or so...). Do you have any ideas why it happen? video https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZAAZ2GL8BR59pRH8mydGQZVCWyljFwX6

Comment: Not sure but try rounding the pixel values and see if it makes a difference

Comment: no it doesn't make any difference :(

Comment: Well, the calculation is accurate but that's the best that the browser can do, it just can't deal with fractions of a pixel better than it's doing right now, so I think it's a technical limitation, but somebody can explain it better than me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I was able to resolve issue with sub-pixels rendering. I've changed an approach slightly - instead of updating left & top coordinates with offset, I've used css translate() to apply the same offset. Works very well.

Seems transform has much better sub-pixels rendering optimizations.

Here is a [codepen example](https://codepen.io/vdenisenko-waverley/pen/eYmRyQE).

```
function updateElement() {
    obj.style.left = l + 'px';
    obj.style.top = t + 'px';
    obj.style.width = w + 'px';
    obj.style.height = h + 'px';
    obj.style.transform = 'rotate(' + r + 'deg) translate(' + ox + 'px, ' + oy + 'px)';
}
```

Same formula might be reused with slight adjustments to preserve any of rectangle corners.

Answer (score 2):

If you apply the transforms relative to the top left corner (`transform-origin: top left`), then you don't need to calculate that correction factor. You can then wrap all the shapes if you need to position them on the page:

```js
const obj = document.querySelector('.object');
const btn = document.querySelector('button');

let h = 100;
let w = 100;

btn.addEventListener('click', () => { 
  h += 5;
  w += 5;
  
  updateElement();
});

function updateElement() {
  obj.style.width = w + 'px';
  obj.style.height = h + 'px';
}

updateElement();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

button {
  margin: 8px;
  padding: 8px;
  font-family: monospace;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background: transparent;
}

.container {
  position: relative;   
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.object-initial {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  left: 30%;
  outline: 1px dashed black;
  transform: rotate(20deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.object {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  left: 30%;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  transform: rotate(20deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
}
```

```html
<button>Increase width and height</button>

<div class="container">
  <div class="object"></div>

  <div class="object-initial"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear, the origin can't be changed - it should be center as there are many user interactions based on it.

Comment: @Vytalyi It is impossible to preserve both left top and center position.

Comment: Okay, so the center is obviously will be moved. I understand it. However origin should stay 'center'. In my simplified example I'm updating width and height which is similar to dragging bottom-right object corner. So I want the opposite corner to keep initial position to provide better UX. I'm quite sure its possible.

Comment: I'm positioning the element absolutely by specifying top and left coordinates. So I need to calculate left & top values, not sure if I can use "newcenter" in my calculations...